# Incorrect output format when translating DNA to Protein

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I know that this question has been asked before but I'm getting some really weird output from this. Basically I'm trying to convert a DNA sequence in .fasta format (i.e. an identifier beginning with a ">" followed by the sequence on the next line) to amino acid letters in the same format. I have the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

def translate_dna(sequence):

    codontable = {
    'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W',
    'ATG':'M'
    }
    proteinsequence = ''
    start = sequence.find('ATG')
    sequencestart = sequence[int(start):]
    stop = sequencestart.find('TAA')
    cds = str(sequencestart[:int(stop)+3])

    for n in range (0,len(cds),3):
            if cds[n:n+3] in codontable:
                    proteinsequence += codontable[cds[n:n+3]]
                    print proteinsequence
            sequence = ''

header = ''
sequence = ''
for line in open(filename):
    if line[0] == ">":
            if header != '':
                    print header
                    translate_dna(sequence)

            header = line.strip()
            sequence = ''
    else:
            sequence += line.strip()

print header
translate_dna(sequence)
```

My output is expected to come out like this:
mouse_IPS1_cds
MFAEDKTY (and so on and so on)

But I actually get this where it prints a new letter each line and does not complete to the end of the sequence:
mouse_IPS1_cds
M
MF
MFA
MFAE
MFAED
MFAEDK
MFAEDKT
MFAEDKTY (it stops here when it should be longer)

The output thus makes this kind of half triangle incomplete list of letters that just increases by one each line.

Please, is there any way someone could point out what's making this happen? Why would it be printing a new letter each line and then not even finish the sequence?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing `proteinsequence` on every iteration through the loop in which you're building it. As a result, you get each intermediate version. Move the print statement to the end of the loop, like this, and you'll only print out the final product:

```
for n in range (0,len(cds),3):
        if cds[n:n+3] in codontable:
                proteinsequence += codontable[cds[n:n+3]]
        sequence = ''
print proteinsequence
```

Comment: Oh, of course! So simple, I can't believe I missed that, thanks! For some reason it stops translating in the middle of the sequence though...not sure why. I'm trying to see something in the code that would prevent it from going further in the sequence. I don't understand how it translates some but not all.

Comment: Hmm, that does sound strange. It's hard to say why that would be happening without seeing the example FASTA file, but two things in your code that seem strange are: 1) You check to see if the codon is in the codon table - there is an appropriate amino acid to associate with and sequence of three bases, so there should never be a codon that isn't in the table. 2) Is there a reason you're setting sequence = '' in the for loop? I think it's harmless, but seems unnecessary. I doubt those would cause a stop half-way through, but they might be good starting points?

Comment: (I assume you've already checked for an unexpected stop codon somewhere in the middle. And I also assume that there's a reason that you're only stopping at one out of the three stop codons)

Comment: Got everything worked out. Thanks again for your help!